# order of imports styles changes (scss and bootstrap) in lazy loading imports

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4, lazy-loading

I'm trying to add a second theme to project by lazy loading styles files based on a condition in ThemeSelector.js, and in consequence the order of styles changes, always the bootstrap imported last and i cant override it in scss/css files without the !important, how can I force it to respect the order of imports?

ThemeSelector.js:

```
import React, { Suspense, Fragment, lazy } from 'react'

const Theme1 = lazy(() => import('./themes/Theme1'))
const Theme2 = lazy(() => import('./themes/Theme2'))
const condition = ...

const ThemeSelector = ({ children }) => {
   return (
    <Fragment>
      {/* Conditionally render theme based on condition */}
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        {!condition && <Theme1 />}
        {condition && <Theme2 />}
      </Suspense>
      {children}
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default ThemeSelector
```

index.js

```
import...
import...
import ThemeSelector from 'styles/ThemeSelector'
import App from './App'

...
...
ReactDOM.render(
    <ThemeSelector>
      <App />
    </ThemeSelector>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Theme1.js

```
import '../../theme1.css'
const Theme1 = () => null
export default Theme1
```

Theme2.js

```
import '../../theme2.css'
const Theme2 = () => null
export default Theme2
```